# get object's value as type from array of objects in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects that is like,

```
const myObj = [
  { key: 'orange', value: 1 },
  { key: 'apple', value: 1 }
]
```

Now, I want to extract type, `'orange' | 'apple'` from `myObj` array. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to extract `orange` and `apple` which are the keys or do you want to extract the _values_ for those keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do two things.
Use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to narrow the type of your `object` as much as possible. And then extract the key generically.

```
const myObj = [
  { key: 'orange', value: 1 },
  { key: 'apple', value: 1 }
] as const;

type keyType = typeof myObj[number]['key'];
```

Const assertion does a few things to you `myObj` above, one of them being - prevention of widening of types. So instead of `key` being inferred as `string` it gets inferred as `orange | apple`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDaAoGGAbxgGsBTBALhgHIQAnAQzAHNzaAaGANyYBsAruRoBGGAF9OBYmUo1aTAA5L+HbnyEiY4iXgC6MJhBihIUANx48UBEvJyEAFTsPst+yABm8ZOhxggnAo5Az6OLQUCLT6VnhAA)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to declare the array `as const`, so that TS can infer concrete string values and not just `string` type.

```js
const myObj = [
  { key: 'orange', value: 1 },
  { key: 'apple', value: 1 }
] as const
```

And then extract the values

```js
type Fruit = typeof myObj[number]['key']
```

The `number` just denotes that you are referencing all array items, not a concrete item.